# Check constraint for phone number format

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, check-constraints

I keep getting an error:

> [2020-01-27 10:37:04] [23000][4025] CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed

When I insert the following row:

```
'(01)236-4589'
```

For the following column:

```
CHECK (phone LIKE '(0[0-9])[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I suppose that you meant *phone number* format instead of *date* format in the title of your question.

Comment: `CHECK` was not implemented until MariaDB 10.2 and MySQL 8.0.16.  Fixes were added in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with your code:

- to check a value against a regex, you need to use the `REGEXP` operator instead of `LIKE`
- the opening and closing parenthese need to be escaped (this requires two backslashes)

Also, you can use quantifiers to avoid repeating `[0-9]` again and again.

Consider:

```
CHECK (phone REGEXP '\\(0[0-9]\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f88eba0ed12c8c73b459dbdd5a82ce11)**

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? @downvoter, please elaborate.